# Refer to variable within a class

Tags: excel, vba, class

Trying to call a variable, FirstandLastName (underlined in pic), but get

> Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

```vb
Function haskey(Team_x_Array As Collection, Team_X_Tab_Names As Variant) As Boolean
    ictr = Team_x_Array.Count

    For Each persondetails In Team_x_Array
    
        If FirstandLastName = Team_X_Tab_Names Then
            x = "Name Found!"
        Else
            x = "Name not found"
        End If
            
    Next persondetails
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Edit:

```vb
Function haskey(Team_x_Array As Collection, Team_X_Tab_Names As Variant) As Boolean
    ictr = Team_x_Array.Count

    For Each persondetails In Team_x_Array
    
            If persondetails.FirstandLastName = Team_X_Tab_Names Then
                x = "Name Found!"
            Else
                x = "Name not found"
            End If
            
    Next persondetails
End Function
```

[image]

Customer Class
[image]

Comment: `persondetails.FirstandLastName` maybe?

Comment: tried it, but that doesn't work

Comment: Can you show us what your attempt looks like?

Comment: Do you want me to just post my entire code?

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: No need for that... just update your question to show how my suggestion "didn't work" - maybe the syntax you used was wrong...

Comment: Ohhh my bad. Yeah Just posted it

Comment: It will have to be referenced as `persondetails.FirstandLastName`.  But  it will have to be declared as Public in clsCustomer.

Comment: You compare FirstandLastName (Variant /Empty) with Team_X_Tab_Names (clsTeamAWorkSheetTabs). This class not have default method.

Comment: Looks like you are using `persondetails` as a public variable and then also using it as the control variable on your loop. That's most likely causing a problem. I could be wrong.

Comment: Should I change the one in the public variable?

Comment: Here's the link for the full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/10viZTNtY3PHaRJr8PRZYwklf1Q-qLlUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think, Your error not in persondetails side, bat on ``Team_X_Tab_Names`` side.  Should be ``persondetails.FirstandLastName = Team_X_Tab_Names.SomeMethod``

Comment: I would remove the public definition and define it in the subroutine instead - and not as a Variant. That's me tho.